# Magento 2: Get IP address from order

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order

How to get IP address from order ID in Magento 2? Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can order ip from**

> $orderObejct->getRemoteIp()

**Best solution is:**

> echo $order->getRemoteIp(); echo $order->getXForwardedFor() ? ' (' .
>   $order->getXForwardedFor() . ')' : '';